# Django query database for multiple combinations of keywords

Tags: python, django

I have a table in Django as follows:

```
class TableName(models.Model):
    key_one = models.CharField()
    key_two = models.CharField()
    list = models.TextField()
```

The table is used to return a `list` for a set of user-input keywords. If a user inputs `ABC`, `DEF`, it'll return the list associated with

```
key_one = ABC
key_two = DEF
```

At the same time, if user inputs `DEF`, `ABC`, then it'll return a different list.

These two are very straightforward. The tricky part comes into play when more than 2 keywords are entered: `ABC`, `DEF`, `GHI`.

Now the query should check the Table for

```
key_one = ABC
key_two = DEF

key_one = DEF
key_two = ABC

key_one = ABC
key_two = GHI

key_one = GHI
key_two = ABC

key_one = DEF
key_two = GHI

key_one = GHI
key_two = DEF
```

I, however, cannot seem to figure a query for this sort of input data. Would really appreciate some help in figuring this one out.

Answer (score 0):

This will likely not perform very well because of the number of logical OR's that the query will contain, but here's how you could do it in a single query:

```
from itertools import permutations
from django.db.models import Q

keys = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI']
q_object = None
for key_one, key_two in permutations(keys, 2):
    permutation_q = Q(key_one=key_one, key_two=key_two)
    if q_object is None:
        q_object = permutation_q
    else:
        q_object |= permutation_q

results = TableName.objects.filter(q_object)
```

Another way to handle it is if you only have 4 different values for key_one and key_two, where three of them are `'ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI'` and the fourth is `'XYZ'`. Then the following would be a better choice:

```
results = TableName.objects.all().exclude(
    key_one='XYZ').exclude(key_two='XYZ')
```

This takes advantage of knowing that the only values in TableName will be those that don't contain `'XYZ'` in either key_one or key_two.